# no idea how to do it use python3.x , i tried s.split('!') but not working in this case

Tags: python-3.x

```
def split_on_separators(original, separators):
    """ (str, str) -> list of str

    Return a list of non-empty, non-blank strings from the original string
    determined by splitting the string on any of the separators.
    separators is a string of single-character separators.

    >>> split_on_separators("Hooray! Finally, we're done.", "!,")
    ['Hooray', ' Finally', " we're done."]
    """



    # To do: Complete this function's body to meet its specification.
    # You are not required to keep the two lines below but you may find
    # them helpful. (Hint)
    result = [original]
    return result
```

Comment: Looks like the same here...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22241667/i-cant-make-the-function-completely-correct/22241936?noredirect=1#comment33777537_22241936

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it.

```
    def split_on_separators(original, separators):
        """ (str, str) -> list of str

        Return a list of non-empty, non-blank strings from the original string
        determined by splitting the string on any of the separators.
        separators is a string of single-character separators.

        >>> split_on_separators("Hooray! Finally, we're done.", "!,")
        ['Hooray', ' Finally', " we're done."]
        """

        result = [original]
        for sep in separators:
            r = []
            for sub in result:
                r.extend(sub.split(sep))
            result = r
        return result
```